# Can't find forms in a webpage using Perl module - WWW:Mechanize

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am using the perl module `WWW:Mechanize`

Until now everything was fine, but for a certain webpage it seems unable to find an existing form:

```
<form id="formaction" method="post" action="omadm_locate.php">
```

Although when I print the content of the page, the expected page is printed and its the right page.

I have used `print Dumper($mech->forms());` it gave me nothing;

`$mech->forms` returned nothing;

Everything tells me that the page has no forms although it has, same thing for the input files...

Btw I was able to access other forms in other pages using the excat method.

Comment: Can you post this HTML form code here?

Comment: <form id="formaction" method="post" action="omadm_connectivity.php">
<div id="actions">
<div id="phoneInfoButton">
<div class="divMsisdn">
<label for="msisdn">MSISDN </label>
<input id="msisdn" type="text" value="" name="msisdn">
</div>

Comment: ........toolong</table>
<table id="new_wlan" style="display:none">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

Comment: If the page in question uses JavaScript/AJAX to append the form to the page this module won't work. WWW::Mechanize doesn't support JavaScript. WWW::Mechanize::Firefox is one of many alternatives if this is the case. See also WWW::Mechanize::Shell which may be helpful in debugging your problem.

Comment: Find out if the page in question is performing AJAX by disabling scripts in your browser (Noscript is a plugin that does this) and seeing if the page still contains the form content. If the content really is AJAX, use HTTPLiveHeaders or something similar to inspect the POST headers, and fake those using Mechanize to get the same result.

Comment: Try to use module `WWW::Scripter` for JavaScript and/or Ajax support and print the modified content to see if **<form** is there or not. If yes, then you will be able to get it. If not, then the form is not there at all.

Answer (score 0):

In old versions WWW::Mechanize got errors to search some forms.
It's important if you're using some Linux distribution with customs packages which aren't very updated.