# python mechanize FormNotFoundError

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I am working on mechanize to fetch form element

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("http://www.bnm.gov.my/index.php?ch=12&pg=622")
br.select_form(name="Rates")
```

But this is throwing error:

```
FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'Rates'
```

Even though there is

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" method="get" action="index.php" name="Rates">
```

can some one help on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like there are several elements on the page that have the name and/or id of "rates".  This could be a problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem like mechanize sees any form. `[ i.name for i in br.forms() ]` returns an empty list.

Comment: There's a comment in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345696/cant-find-forms-in-a-webpage-using-perl-module-wwwmechanize) which might explain this behavior. Retrieving the page with `wget` also doesn't produce that form.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the form with the nr param:

```
select_form(self, name=None, predicate=None, nr=None)
```

I guess that page has only 1 form, so try nr=0.

If there is no form in the page, then it probably means that it was added using Javascript. And, in that case, mechanize won't be enough. You will have to use Selenium or Spynner.